# How to mock a.getTypeA().getTypeB();

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, junit5

AClass a=new AClass() ;
a.getTypeA().getTypeB();

I have used mocked constructor to mock AClass method but how to mock getTypeB(); method

I am able to mock class A but for class b it's calling real method.
Method getTypeB() has TypeB class.

Comment: Could you show the test?  What value do you want to get from `getTypeB()`?  What value are you getting now?

Comment: Please provide some code snipped from both classes and test case

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular How do [I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."
even if it is no homework.
Please add  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve).

Comment: You should rethink your design. In Java (like in any OO language) we distinguish between *business classes* (classes that contain actual logic) and *value objects/data transfer objects*, classes that only contain data and (almost) no logic. The point here is, that business classes should not have getters since they violate the **information hiding principle** (one of the most important OOP-rules) and value objects (as well as any `Collection`s) should not be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest way but you need to make sure each object you are referencing is also mocked. You can do that by building out your mocked a object with Mockito's when() method.

You should be able to do something like the following in your test:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AClassTest {

    @Mock
    private AClass a;

    @Mock
    private TypeA typeA;

    @Mock
    private TypeB typeB;

    @Autowired
    private YourController yourController;

    @Test
    void testControllerInSomeWay() {

        when(typeA.getTypeB()).thenReturn(typeB);
        when(a.getTypeA()).thenReturn(typeA);

        yourController.useAClassInSomeWay(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`; this is not a SpringBootTest. As presented, all fields will be null and the test will fail.

Comment: I ran it with `@SpringBootTest` and it works. I'm not entirely sure why as I agree that I should have either used `@MockBean` with `@SpringBootTest` or `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` with `@Mock`. The puzzling thing is it works as is just fine with `@SpringBootTest`

Comment: @knittl Just as a quick follow up I went down a rabbit hole and discovered that `@SpringBootTest` includes many of the same features as `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` and `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`. To your point it's probably over kill to use @SpringBootTest if you aren't trying to load the entire application context and all the Spring bloat. But I suppose it _does_ still work.

Comment: thanks for verifying :) I was under the impression that it does not work, but alas, I was wrong. Running as `@SpringBootTest` will start the entire application context, which is overkill for a simple test like this, as you have mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: @knittl of course! Thank you for the inspiration to figure out how all these annotations work. I didn't have much of an idea what all the differences were before.